# Phabricator: running over https, doesn't load any images. Firefox reports blocking unencrypted content

Tags: encryption, https, phabricator

Phabricator: running over https, doesn't load any images. Firefox reports blocking unencrypted content.

If I click that little shield thingy next to 'https', and select "Disable protection for now" with "Options" button, things seem to work fine.

I added https:// in phabricator.production-uri and phabricator.allowed-uris with no luck.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found it:

```
bin/config set phabricator.base-uri https://<your-base-url>
bin/phd restart
```

I had previously added that https url in phabricator.production-uri and phabricator.allowed-uris (I don't know if that mattered).

Warning: At one point, I was able to complete messup the login screen. Probably because I didn't run `bin/phd restart`. If that happens, restore `phabricator.base-uri` to its previous value.

Comment: Thanks for this tip!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to setting **phabricator.base-uri**, you may also need to change **security.alternate-file-domain** to use HTTPS. Read https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/configuring_file_domain/ to find more about this setting.

Alternatively, you can simply delete the setting by running `bin/config delete security.alternate-file-domain`.

Answer (score 1):

This same issue occurred to me after installing a TLS certificate.
Setting the base-uri option did not work for me, nor did the production or allowed uri options.

What solved it was setting the **security.alternate-file-domain** parameter to the https url, as explained here: https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/configuring_file_domain/

Perhaps this isn't the optimal solution, but it's not clear what else to do.

My setup: Bitnami Phabricator pre-configured instance over AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like now the way to go is to screate a `support/preamble.php` which contains nothing but

```
<?php

$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = true;
```

as described [here](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/configuring_preamble/)